# Working with post values in the admin panel

Tags: wp-admin, theme-options

I have this basic admin page

functions.php

> `<?php include('ui.php'); ?>`

ui.php

```
<?php
function gui()
{
    include('gui.php');
}
function add_page()
{
    $themename = 'Cesaro';
    $page_function = 'gui';
    add_menu_page( $themename." Options", $themename, 'edit_themes', $page_function, 'gui' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_page' );
?>
```

gui.php

```
<form name="input" action="post_options_from_form.php" method="post">
    <article>
        <label>Firstname</label><input type="text" class="x-input"/>
    </article>
    <article>
        <label>Lastname</label><input type="text" class="x-input"/>
    </article>
    <article>
        <label>City</label><input type="text" class="x-input"/>
    </article>
    <input type="submit" value="Update Options" class="x-button"/>
</form>
```

When i click update options,i get the error

```
The requested URL /wp-admin/post_options_from_form.php was not found on this server.
```

How do i make sure that post values end up my php i specified in the post action?.My post php file is `post_options_from_form.php`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
<form name="input" action="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ).'/'.'post_options_from_form.php'; ?>" method="post">
```

although i wanted post_options_from_form.php to be an admin page.

Edit:

This finally worked as i was able to post to the admin page i created

```
<form name="input" action="admin.php?page=admin_page" method="post">
```

On the function,

```
function admin_page()
{
require('post_options_from_form.php');
}
```

Comment: Just using `<form name="input" method="post">` is enough.

Comment: No its not enough.